# google geocode cannot find address but google maps can

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am trying to resolve an address using Google gecode. The address is imported from elsewhere or user entered and not very orderly.

With the address spaced out like this:

O/s NCP Car Park, Coram St Jn Woburn Place  London WC1

or spaces replaced with "+"

O/s+NCP+Car+Park,Coram+St+Jn+Woburn+Place+London+WC1

My code will attempt to match the address in full and then word by word will remove leading words until a match occurs.

In Google Maps this resolves fine but even when my address is reduced to

"Woburn Place London WC1"

gecode will not resolve.

These seems to me to be a pretty tidy address with capital city and postcode.

Should I be using some other maps function?

I already tried autocomplete+places and that was resolving even less of my addresses list.

thanks all,

jON

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Maps Places API textSearch](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) finds two results for that string ("O/s NCP Car Park,Coram St Jn Woburn Place London WC1"):

```
Found 2 results for O/s NCP Car Park,Coram St Jn Woburn Place London WC1
[ 0 ]: London, United Kingdom (51.523813, -0.12609699999995883)
[ 1 ]: Woburn Place, Coram St, London WC1H 0ND, United Kingdom (51.5238677, -0.12642860000005385)
```

To use the geocoding API you need to use "WC1H" for the postcode:

```
Found 1 results for O/s NCP Car Park,Coram St Jn Woburn Place London WC1H
[ 0 ]: Woburn Pl, London WC1H, UK (51.5237701, -0.12688589999993383)
```

url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=O/s%20NCP%20Car%20Park,Coram%20St%20Jn%20Woburn%20Place%20London%20WC1H